# Unable to send a post request to Shopify using got

Tags: node.js, post, request, http-post, shopify-api

I have been trying to make a post request using got to shopify's site with add to cart functionalities (following similar structure of https://shopify.dev/api/ajax/reference/cart)

```
const main = async () => {
  const res = await got.get('https://barstoolkicks.com/products.json?limit=250&page=1&order=updated_at').json();
  const productId = res.products[7].id
  const variantId = res.products[7].variants[0].id

  // ATC 
  let data = {
    'items': [{
        // 'form_type': 'product',
        // 'utf8': '✓',
        'id': variantId,
        'quantity': 1 
        }] 
  }

  const atc = await got.post('https://barstoolkicks.com/cart/add.js', {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25'
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
  })

  .then(res => console.log(res.data))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

}

main();
```

It gives me a response of bad request (400) and I'm completely unsure of what to do. Need help to guide me for future post requests using Got (https://www.npmjs.com/package/got)

Comment: This line `data: JSON.stringify(data),` doesn't seem right, since data property is not mentioned in docs. Try this instead `json: data`. It should automatically stringify data and also set content-type header for you.

Comment: @Molda I changed it to to json: data but now I am getting Response Code 422 (Unproccesable Entity). Not sure what I can do to make it successful.

Comment: Have a look at this https://shopify.dev/api/ajax/reference/cart#error-responses